# Homepage image slider stops working on horizontal scrolling website

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been working on a site found here:

http://www.myheavenbridal.com.au

I have a JS problem where the homepage slider stops working once clicking the main navigation links.

ie/ clicking on 'Contact Us' will slide over to the contact page - then clicking back on the 'Home' button returns the user to homepage, however the slider stops loading images.

Any help as to why this is happening or how to fix it would be much appreciated.

Comment: That's a lot of code to sift through to fix your problem. I would start by checking out what you're doing when you slide "home" off the page. Are you hiding it or are you simply moving it off the page?

Answer (score 0):

On your page, you register an event handler (using jQuery's document.ready) - This is responsible for loading the images. The specific code is:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$(function() {
    var myid = $('#cimy_div_id_0');
    if (myid[0]) {
        $('#cimy_div_id_0').crossSlide({
            fade: 7
        }, [
            { src: 'http://www.myheavenbridal.com.au/wp-content/Cimy_Header_Images/0/home_left-right.jpg', from: 'top left 1x', to: 'bottom right 1.2x', time: 5},
            { src: 'http://www.myheavenbridal.com.au/wp-content/Cimy_Header_Images/0/home_right-left.jpg', from: 'top right 1x', to: 'bottom left 1.2x', time: 5},
            { src: 'http://www.myheavenbridal.com.au/wp-content/Cimy_Header_Images/0/home_zoom-01.jpg', from: 'top left 1x', to: 'bottom right 1.2x', time: 5}
        ]);
    }  
});
});
```

When you click the "Contact Us" button, your code removes the images. However, clicking "Home" doesn't run the code above to add the images again. (If you run the code via console, you'll see your images).